# Why I got "Uncaught TypeError" at airconsole-1.4.0.js:669?

Tags: javascript, html, airconsole

I'm new in airconsole, and I just learning it, so maybe this is something usual.
I have this at screen.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var air_console = new AirConsole();

    // Listen for messages from other devices
    air_console.onMessage = function(from, data) {

      // We receive a message -> Send message back to the device
      air_console.message(from, "Full of pixels!");

      // Show message on device screen
      var info = document.createElement('DIV');
      info.innerHTML = data;
      document.body.appendChild(info);
    };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      color: white;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

And I have this in controller.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.7.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var air_console = new AirConsole();

    // Send a message to the screen
    air_console.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, "How are you?");

    // Listen for messages
    air_console.onMessage = function(from, data) {

      // Show message on device screen
      var info = document.createElement('DIV');
      info.innerHTML = data;
      document.body.appendChild(info);
    };
  </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      color: white;
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And I got this error in both of them:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
    at AirConsole.onPostMessage_ (airconsole-1.7.0.js:1012)
    at airconsole-1.7.0.js:927
```

And of course nothing on the screen. What is my mistake here, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the **onReady** event before sending a message:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.airconsole.com/api/airconsole-1.7.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var air_console = new AirConsole();

    air_console.onReady = function() {
      // Send a message to the screen
      air_console.message(AirConsole.SCREEN, "How are you?");
    }

    // Listen for messages
    air_console.onMessage = function(from, data) {

      // Show message on device screen
      var info = document.createElement('DIV');
      info.innerHTML = data;
      document.body.appendChild(info);
    };
  </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      color: white;
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```